# Why AutoSar defines new types other than use the standard one provided by C++ itself?

Tags: autosar

Why AutoSar defines new types(for intance, `ara::core::Future`, `ara::core::Vector` and so on) other than use the standard one(i.e. `std::future`, `std::vector`)?

What's the benefit?

Comment: Please describe the attributes of AUTOSAR types which you are aware of. You might find that there is much more information on ranges, measurement units etc. than in an `unsigned int`. Space missions failed because of unit mistakes made because of implicit assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about the types in chapter 7 and 8 of the AUTOSAR_SWS_AdaptivePlatformCore.pdf.

> **7.2.4.2 Types derived from the base C++ standard**
>
> In addition to AUTOSAR-devised data types, which are mentioned in the previous sections, the Adaptive Platform also contains a number of generic data types and helper
> functions.
>
> Some types are already contained in [4, the C++14 standard]; however, types with almost identical behavior are re-defined within the `ara::core` namespace. The reason
> for this is that the memory allocation behavior of the `std:: types` is often unsuitable for automotive purposes. *Thus, the `ara::core` ones define their own memory allocation behavior, and perform some other necessary adaptions as well, including about the throwing of exceptions.*
>
> **[SWS_CORE_00040] DRAFTg Errors originating from C++ standard classes**
>
> For the classes in ara::core specified below in terms of the corresponding classes of the C++ standard, all functions that are specified by [4, the C++14 standard], [9, the C++17
> standard], or [10, the draft C++20 standard] to throw any exceptions, are instead specified to be the cause of a Violation when they do so.c(RS_AP_00130)
>
> Examples for such data types are: **Array, Vector**, Map, and String.

The reasons for `ara::future` are described also in chapter 8.1.6. (I will not cite this here).

So, in the end, `ara::core` is the place to define / configure the **implementation specific details** in order to use the same definition in the code base in **AUTOSAR Adaptive** SW, no matter if it is your own SW on top of `ara` or within `ara` service implementation itself.

This is like the `Std_Types.h` / `Compiler.h` / `Platform_Types.h` is the place in **AUTOSAR Classic** to define / configure the basic primitive types of `uint8` / `sint8` / ... instead of using `uint8_t` / `int8_t` / ... from `stdint.h`, which was introduced in C99, but was not available in C90.